# python pandas merge по двум столбцам - по символу и ближайшей меньшей дате

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Есть два дата фрейма:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'date': [datetime.date(2022,1,1), datetime.date(2021,1,1),datetime.date(2022,10,1),datetime.date(2021,10,1),]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'date': [datetime.date(2021,10,1), datetime.date(2020,1,1),datetime.date(2021,12,1),datetime.date(2020,12,1),], 'value':[9,10,11,12]})
```

Нужно их смержить так, чтобы получить value по symbol и ближайшей дате меньшей указанной.
reindex  смотрит по дате и разницу берет abs, а надо чтобы была partition по symbol.
Получится должно такое:

```
c=pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'date': [datetime.date(2022,1,1), datetime.date(2021,1,1),datetime.date(2022,10,1),datetime.date(2021,10,1),], 'value':[9,10,11,12]})
```

т.е. для A datetime.date(2022,1,1), берется value из b по A и дате datetime.date(2021,10,1), а для A datetime.date(2021,1,1) берется value из b по A и дате datetime.date(2020,1,1), хоть 2021-10-1 ближе, но дата нужна <.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: ничего умнее этого придумать не удалось: d = a.merge(b, how='cross')
d['delta'] = d['date_x'] - d['date_y']
d[(d['symbol_x']==d['symbol_y']) & (d['date_y'] < d['date_x'])].sort_values(by=['symbol_x','date_x', 'delta']).groupby(by=['symbol_x','date_x']).head(1)

Comment: Код добавляйте в вопрос. Если работает - так и хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

есть такой вариант, но я не уверен на 100%, попробуйте протестировать:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                  'date': [pd.Timestamp(2022,1,1), 
                           pd.Timestamp(2021,1,1),
                           pd.Timestamp(2022,10,1),
                           pd.Timestamp(2021,10,1),]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                  'date': [pd.Timestamp(2021,10,1), 
                           pd.Timestamp(2020,1,1),
                           pd.Timestamp(2021,12,1),
                           pd.Timestamp(2020,12,1),], 
                  'value':[9,10,11,12]})

res = (pd.merge_asof(a.sort_values('date'),b.sort_values('date'),on='date',by='symbol').
       sort_values('symbol'))

print(res)
'''
  symbol       date  value
0      A 2021-01-01     10
2      A 2022-01-01      9
1      B 2021-10-01     12
3      B 2022-10-01     11
```